# plyr.js instantiation causing 503 error in production

Tags: javascript, elixir, phoenix-framework, plyr, brunch

I'm instantiating plyr.js using their beta (3.0.0) in elixir/phoenix and I'm getting [these errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoFE9.png)

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)"

This prevents me from scrolling on the page at all

for whatever reason if I don't include the Plyr instantiation in the JS files, the 503 error goes away. Anyone have any idea why this occurs?

Here is the JS code:

```
import Plyr from 'plyr';

(function() {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

        const plyr = new Plyr('#player', {
            autoplay: true,
            controls: [''],
            fullscreen: {
                enabeled: false
            },
            loop: { 
                active: true }
        });

    });

})()
```

Comment: Not familiar with `Plyr` but in the exception screenshot there is a [object Object] is being passed as a parameter to the service. So your setup might need adjustments

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the fact that this is in beta makes this a legitimate bug. It has been filed to Github.

For now the developers of Plyr recommend using v2 for production